# how to hide and disable fullscreen button in flowplayer

Tags: javascript, html, flowplayer

Plesae any one help me to solve this issue. i have been trying to hide the fullscreen button from the flowplayer. But I can't find a solution.

Here is my js code-

```
<script>
$f("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer3.2.10.swf", {
    key: '#$123456',

    // don't start automatically so we can see the button
    clip: {
        autoPlay: false
    },
    enableFullscreen: 'false'
});
```

I will appreciate if any one can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if

```
fullscreen: false
```

will work.

You can also check

[Flowplayer 1](https://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/setup#disable-fullscreen-and-save)

[Flowplayer 2](https://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/setup#is-there-any-way-to-disable)

Comment: ya its workiing now, i got answer from your second link "Flowplayer 2". Thank you .

Comment: please accept the answer so that it can help others